# FCM web background service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I can´t make it to receive the push message when my web page is on background (the window minimized, or another label), it's only showing the notification which is ok, but nothing happens in my page.js when I try to send a post message back.

sw.js:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    const title = '¡Mensaje Nuevo!';
    const options = {
        body: 'conductor: ' + payload.data.chofer_id + ' - ' + payload.data.mensaje,
        icon: '/icono.png',
    };

    send_message_to_all_clients('sound');

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});

function send_message_to_all_clients(msg) {
    clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
        clients.forEach(client => {
            send_message_to_client(client, msg).then(m => console.log("SW Received Message: " + m));
        })
    })
}

function send_message_to_client(client, msg) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

        msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function (event) {
            if (event.data.error) {
                reject(event.data.error);
            } else {
                resolve(event.data);
            }
        };

        client.postMessage("SW Says: '" + msg + "'", [msg_chan.port2]);
    });
}
```

page.js

```
// Handler for messages coming from the service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log("Client 1 Received Message: " + event.data);
    $.playSound('Sounds/Tethys.mp3');
});
```

When I send a message and I'm on the web page, the console log shows and the sound plays:

Client 1 Received Message: [object Object]

But never in background.

Please somebody help, it has been long months.

Answer (score 2):

finally i found my problem!

i was sending the FCM message with the notification section and it was preventing to post the message back to my page with the service worker function.

```
{
  "to": "<token>",
 "notification": { // this was the problem
    "body": "test"
  }
  "data": {
    "chofer_id": 3,
    "mensaje": "hola"
  }
}
```